# Proving a set is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

I'm trying to prove that $\{x \in \mathbb{R}: 10 \sqrt(x) - x > 0\}$ is bounded. I know $x=0$ is the greatest lower bound from the conditions and $x=25$ is the least upper bound from the derivatives of the function (am I allowed to do this?). I was just wondering how to formally write the proof. Would I just say $-25 < 0$ so $-25< x < 25$ and $|x|< 25$ so $S$ is bounded by definition?

Comment: [mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) - for future questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you think $U$ is the least upper bound for this set (by the way, $U\neq 25$).  To prove this, you need to show two things:

1. For any $x$ in the set, $x\leq U$. (This establishes that $U$ is an upper bound.)
2. If $U'$ is another upper bound (i.e., satisfies the first condition), then $U\leq U'$.  (This shows that $U$ is the *least* upper bound.)

What do you think the analogous conditions are for the greatest lower bound $L$?

Comment: For any x in the set L is less than or equal to x. If L prime is another lower bound then L prime is less than or equal to L. Would i i find these conditions and then use induction to show they hold?

Comment: Those are the correct conditions for $L$.  Induction is not needed.  Simply choose $U$, prove that the two conditions hold, and then choose $L$ and prove that the two conditions for greatest lower bound hold.  Note that since all you're asked to prove is that the set is bounded, you don't actually have to show that $L$ and $U$ are the greatest and least such bounds, respectively.  You only have to show that there is some lower bound and some upper bound.  But showing greatest/least as well won't hurt.

Comment: So would it be sufficient to say x > 0 for all x since the set is defined to be greater than 0 and showing that x < 26 because solving the equation 10sqrt(x)-x =26 yields nonreal answers?

Comment: Almost.  The only problem is that 26 doesn't work.  You'll need to try something like 101 instead.  Have a look at the graph of $f(x)=10\sqrt{x}-x$.

Comment: Oh ok. The graph shows me a parabola-like graph that starts at x=0 and extends to a maximum height of 25 before continuing downwards infinitely. I'll double check I entered the function correctly but either way 101 would certainly work. Thank you!

Comment: Right.  We're not worried about the maximum value of $10\sqrt{x}-x$; we're worried about the biggest $x$ value that makes $10\sqrt{x}-x>0$.  Notice that if $x=100$, then $10\sqrt{x}-x=0$, and for positive numbers less than 100, $10\sqrt{x}-x>0$.  Happy to help!